# extra space in SSRS report Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to get rif the extra space in the chart of this SSRS report? It has got location names on X-axis, number of employees in each location on Y-axis.

Between Y-axis and first location, there is lot of extra space. Similarly after last location also. please advise.
Let me know if you need any further info.

[image: ssrs1]

[image: 2]

Comment: What category are your series being based on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved by increasing the 'PointWidth' value in properties panel.

Comment: The Properties Panel for what object?

Comment: Properties Panel of the Series.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the Horizontal Axis Properties
2. Under Axis Options-->
    Select Side margins to disabled
3. Click OK

Comment: 30 minutes of google searching, 1 minute answer.  Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select the Chart Axis, and in the Properties look for the Margin property (under Scale).  Set it to False.